# Weighting with Cast Modifier

Tags: animation, weight-painting, vertex-weights

Is there anyway to use weight paint to determine the influence on different parts of an object while using the cast modifier? If not, is there any other way something like this could be achieved (maybe something with vertex groups)?

Comment: Why not? Did you try that? Do you have any problems?

Comment: Have you tried using the *Vertex Group* option on the modifier? Vertex groups are vertex weights in Blender

Answer (score 1):

This is what the *Vertex Group* option is for:

1. Start weight painting; a vertex group will be automatically generated.
2. Select that group in the cast modifier:

[image]

Note that *Vertex Groups* and *Vertex Weights* are really the same thing; the weights seen in *Weight Paint* mode belong to the highlighted vertex group in *Properties > Object > Data > Vertex Groups*.